# Expand aliases in non-interactive shells

Tags: zsh, csh, tcsh

In `bash`, we can use `shopt -s expand_aliases` to expand aliases in scripts.

What are the equivalent commands for `zsh`, `csh`, and `tcsh`? Do they even exist?

In focusing my efforts on `zsh`, I haven’t found such a command. I even tried sourcing the file with the aliases inside the script, but it did not work.

Comment: zsh seems to expand alias in default. Could you write some example code which does not work in zsh ?

Comment: If I have my aliases set in (for example) `~/.zshrc` and I `source ${HOME}/.zshrc` at the top of a script, that script will not be able to use the aliases that exist in `~/.zshrc`.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

For `zsh` you can use `setopt aliases`

```
#!/usr/bin/zsh

alias hoo="echo bar"
unsetopt aliases
hoo # outputs `./test.zsh:5: command not found: hoo`
setopt aliases
hoo # outputs `bar`
```

see `man zshoptions` for detail.

For `csh` and `tcsh`, sourcing the files (`source ${HOME}/.cshrc`, for example) suffices.

Comment: Figured out how to do it in `csh` and `tcsh`: using `source` on the relevant files suffices.

Comment: the option `aliases` is on by default in `zsh` (at least, as of Feb 2019)